# Proving unique solution for $f$ when $f(P_a \cdot a+P_b \cdot b)=P_a \cdot f(a)+P_b \cdot f(b)$

Tags: probability, functions

This problem is about expected value, and it's a real world problem.

I know so far that $f$ is strictly increasing, if that makes the proof more concise (but if you can also prove it without this assumption, that would be awesome). Find all solutions for $f$ when $f(P_a \cdot a+P_b \cdot b)=P_a \cdot f(a)+P_b \cdot f(b)$ for all $a,b \in R$, and for $P_a,P_b \in R_+$. I'm 80% sure $f$ must be $f(x)=mx$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What is the definition of expected value?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $P_a, a, P_b, b$, or are they arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: Expected value is the probability of an event times the outcome of the event summed for all events. So a die role has an expected value of 3.5, for example. Here's a link: http://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/expected-value/

Comment: @B.Mehta, probabilities must be non-negative, so I've edited in that restriction to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking $P_b=0$, you have $f(P_a \cdot a) = P_a \cdot f(a)$ for any $a$ and $P_a$.

Taking $a=1$ shows that $f(P_a) = P_a \cdot f(1)$ for any $P_a$.

For purely cosmetic reasons you can rewrite the last result as $f(x) = x \cdot f(1)$ for all $x$.

Letting $m:=f(1)$ shows that $f(x) = mx$.

This shows that a necessary condition for $f$ to satisfy the original condition is "$f$ must be of the form $f(x)=mx$ where $m:=f(1)$." To show it is also a sufficient condition, you can directly check that the original condition holds with this kind of $f$.

---

The question was edited (after my original answer) to assert $P_a , P_b \ge 0$.

The same argument as before shows that $f(x) = f(1) \cdot x$ for $x \ge 0$.
Then by applying the original assumption, we have $f(-1) + f(1) = f(-1 + 1) = f(0) = 0$ and thus $f(-1) = f(1)$. Applying the same argument before shows $f(-x) = f(-1) \cdot x = f(1) \cdot x$ for $x \ge 0$. Thus $f(x)=f(1) \cdot x$ for all real $x$.

Comment: I really really like this, but it only proves that no non-linear function satisfies the requirements. If you edit your answer to say something like "Then substitute $f=mx$ into the original equation and show that the left-hand side is equal to the right-hand side", I'll confirm your answer.

Comment: Note that $P_a \geq 0$, so you need to show $f(x) = x \cdot f(1)$ for negative $x$ also.

Comment: Hmm but if $P_a$ depends on $a$, then setting $a=1$ we get $f(P_1)=P_1 f(1)$ and not $f(x)=mx$ for $every$ $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, no?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For all $P_a$, $P_b\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $\lambda\in[0,1]$ your condition gives that the fuction is convex and concave, so its graph is an interval with $x$-ends $P_a$ and $P_b$.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @bEPIK The condition $\forall \lambda\in[0,1] f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ is a definition of a convex function on the interval. Since $-f$ is also convex, we have that $f$ is linear (i.e. $ax+b$) and this interval. Setting $y=0$ gives $b=0$.